# Marketplace that allows payment on behalf of third party

Tags: payment

I am currently developing a marketplace type of website. When it comes to handling payments, I would like to be able to charge customers on behalf of sellers.

Which payment gateway API should I use (if this is even possible)? I am using React and Node.

Comment: Aren't this questions for the client/product owner ? It has nothing to do with architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, what I was looking for was something like Stripe Connect. According to their website: "Marketplaces and platforms use Stripe Connect to accept money and pay out to third parties. Connect provides a complete set of building blocks to support virtually any business model, including on-demand businesses, e‑commerce, crowdfunding, and travel and events."